# ¿Existe en español un verbo para "hacer que algo necesario esté hecho"?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, japonés

En japonés existe un verbo que significa "hacer algo en preparación para" o "hacer que algo necesario esté hecho". ¿Existe un verbo en español que represente más o menos estas ideas? ¿O es inevitable usar todas esas frases entre comillas para decir lo mismo?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner una frase de ejemplo? Leyendo la pregunta tal y como está, el verbo *preparar* parece encajar con la definición...

Comment: @wimi la única frase que encontré está en Inglés y realmente no me dice nada: "I'll take care of that." (me ocuparé de eso, o me encargaré de eso) pero no creo que esa oración este capturando la esencia de la palabra, porque la definición no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la forma ～ておく?

Comment: Me suena como a una palabra que usarían en un trabajo o en una cadena de producción (más sabiendo como son los japoneses fanáticos del trabajo, capaz tienen palabras especificas para eso), pero es una suposición nada más

Comment: @Charlie gracias no era un verbo era una forma listada como si fuera un verbo, ahora entendi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En japonés, el verbo "oku" significa "colocar", "poner en su sitio". Si se combina con un verbo en su forma de "-te", pasa a significar lo que comentas: "hacer algo en previsión de otra cosa", "hacer algo por adelantado", "hacer algo en preparación de otra cosa", etc.

Generalmente, esa forma verbal se suele dejar sin traducir dado que en la frase en español muchas veces el significado va ya implícito. Te pongo un ejemplo:

> 学校の電話番号を書いてください
> Gakko no denwabango wo kaite kudasai.
> *Apunta el número de teléfono de la escuela.*
>
> 学校の電話番号を書いておいてください
> Gakko no denwabango wo kaite oite kudasai.
> *Apunta el número de teléfono de la escuela (para que no se te olvide / por si acaso se te olvida / para que lo tengas a mano / etc).*

Como ves, es complicado expresarlo en pocas palabras, y generalmente dependerá del contexto. En este caso se me ocurren algunas alternativas:

> Apunta el teléfono de la escuela, anda.
> Apunta el teléfono de la escuela por si acaso.

Sin embargo, fíjate en este otro ejemplo:

> パソコンを消さないでください
> Pasokon wo kesanaide kudasai.
> *No apagues el ordenador.*
>
> パソコンを消さないでおいてください
> Pasokon wo kesanaide oite kudasai.
> *Asegúrate de no apagar el ordenador.*

En el segundo caso se está expresando que el ordenador no se debe apagar en previsión de algo (puede que esté actualizándose, o que el usuario haya dejado un proceso importante en segundo plano). En la traducción simplemente he hecho énfasis con el verbo "asegurar", pero no creo que ese verbo traduzca exactamente lo que la forma en japonés quiere expresar. Veamos el último ejemplo, muy a colación de lo que pasó con la pandemia:

> トイレットペーパーを買っておく
> Toiretto peepaa wo katte oku.
> *Comprar papel higiénico (en previsión de que tengamos que estar encerrados con el confinamiento).*

Aquí tal vez una traducción adecuada podría ser "aprovisionarse de papel higiénico", pero como ves, una vez más el contexto cambia la forma de expresar el significado de "-teoku".